# Getting 400 response for auth using method post in python request

Tags: python, api, post

I'm trying to send a POST request in python. But server response 400. I tried to use solutions . Both cases I'm getting error code 400, but if I send same request via postman it response 200, and works properly. Server API using "`http`"

```
import requests
import json
headers={'Content-type':'application/json'}

resp = requests.post('http://##########/api_demo/api/v1/auth',data= {"username": "xyz","password": "xyz"},auth=('xyz', 'xyz'),headers=headers)
print (resp)
```

getting 400 bad request , expected should be 200 ok with token in output

Comment: This is almost always a headers/preflight/options problem.

Comment: Btw, why is an auth server using http instead of https? It's transfering passwords in cleartext!